# how to show up animation at activity launch

Tags: android

i have a launcher activity which shows up the blank screen at the start up..i want to show up some animation using an animatd.gif...i initialize my layouts viz home etc when the oncreate of launcher is called, but how do i add some animated image until my first layout is shown..i also doubt whether android supports animated gifs or i have to do a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Animated gifs are not supported  for multiple reasons like "animated .gif are memory hogs", the workaround must be an animation

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html